# Password authentication failed for a user not in my role list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

I am currently trying to run a service using ruby on rails, while running the command `rake db:schema:load`

I got a password not provided error, checking my database.yml file I found this line:

`#password:`

I removed the comment but got the same error so I actually specified a dummy password like so:

```
password: dummy
```

Then I got this error

```
password authentication failed for user "ivan"
```

After this I tried [this solution](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/firstconnect.html) to actually set my password as dummy I still get the same error, my pg_hba.conf has the following line:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

Changing peer to md5 produces the same error, after checking my postgres roles the only one listed is "postgres" not "ivan", what is the cause of this role appearing when trying to run my command and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you share your `database.yml` ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Do you have a user `postgres` ?

Comment: open postgres and update password `ALTER USER ivan WITH PASSWORD 'password';
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new user in postgres . please try below commands for creating new role and user

```
sudo su postgres

psql
du # for checking all existing roles
CREATE ROLE ivan WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'ivan123';
du # check whether this role created or not
```

then add database user name as 'ivan' and password as 'ivan123' in your database.yml

Comment: The best way to say thanks is upvote and accept the answer ;)